# Junit Test Case for exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

```
public class TipException extends Exception {
    private final Object mSource;
    private final Object mObjectInError;
    private final Throwable mCause;

    public TipException(Object source, Object objectInError, Throwable cause, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.mSource = source;
        this.mObjectInError = objectInError;
        this.mCause = cause;
    }
}
```

I need to write Junit test case for this simple exception class having some more methods.
But Since I am new to Junit, Idk how to pass some object with exception here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Exceptions are classes like others, so you can test constructor and "business" logic like others. What and how should you test?

Answer (score 4):

Try something simple like:

```
 public class TipExceptionTest extends TestCase {
 private final String message = "Exception";
 private final TipException tipException= new TipException("source", "MyObject.class", new NullPointerExcepiton(), message);

 @Test
 public void testTipExceptionWithMessage() {
    Assert.assertEquals(tipException.getMessage(), message);//and if you exposed getter/setter for source etc you could assert as well
 }
}
```